# Gartic.io - how does it work? XHR requests

Tags: xmlhttprequest

How does this site work?

They have FORM and input submit, but I don't see XHR's.... there's just "ping" that is being sent frequently with no content (just number 1)

How do they get the data?
Why is it that I don't see it in chrome console?

Weird...

Answer (score 0):

Oh, okay... looks like Socket.IO... very interesting